# How to distinguish if sumproduct needs to be inserted with CSE or not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I sometimes use the inherent array functionality of sumproduct to avoid havingt to enter formulas with Control + Shift + Enter. But it isn't always working. For example

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B2:F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:F2,M$2:M$10,"")))*N$2:N$10)
```

would work, while

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--IF(ISNUMBER(N6:N9),N6:N9))
```

would not.

It isn't really obvious to me, why the first one gives correct results, while the second does not.

Comment: A good question. My personal experience is that if it is not returning the expected result or returning an error, I will try it again with CSE.

Comment: Yes, thats also my common practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question. Rule of thumb for me > You see `IF` and a range to be analized > you press CSE.

Why? Some functions handle CSE natively for you (`SUMPRODUCT` being one of them), but others do not, for example `SUM` but definately also `IF`. Have a look [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/cse) and [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula). Bottom line of the theory (AFAIK) is that CSE will disable something called "implicit intersection" which is explained [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection). It comes down to:

> *"Implicit intersection occurs when a range is passed to a function that expects a **scalar (single) value**. In
>   this situation, Excel will try to resolve the formula using a
>   reference in the same row, or in the same column......Entering an
>   array formula with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (CSE) explicitly disables
>   the implicit intersection behavior. This makes it possible to create
>   formulas that manipulate multiple values input as ranges."*

Because you use `IF`, it doesn't matter it's within `SUMPRODUCT`. You'll still need to press CSE to disable the native "implicit intersection" that comes with using `IF`.

---

***FWIW***: Some additional information on the behaviour called "implicit intersection".

Let's imagine the following data:

[image]

I created a named range called `Vals` from the range `A2:C2`. Now the formula in `B5` is simply `=Vals` but the result is `Val5`. Meaning implicit intersection returned the value from my named range that intersected with the column I entered the formula in.

Why? Because in the background (unseen) Excel used the implicit intersection operator ("@") to return a single value from the intersection just mentioned. Would I use CSE (read, removing the logical operator), the value returned would be `Val2` (top-left value in the array).

> *"Implicit intersection logic reduces many values to a single value. Excel did this to force a formula to return a single value, since a
>   cell could only contain a single value."*

The logical operator "@" will prevent the return of an array and makes sure you'll get a single value returned. Removing this logical operator (is what we do by pressing CSE, or by using functions that do so natively) will make the formula return the array.

You may not see/know about this operator but with the comming of dynamic array formulas they will be in your formulas a lot more. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) MS-documentation on the matter. With those new functionalities, removing the logical operator will not only return the array, it will actually spill the values to neighboring cells. Hence the term "Dynamic array formulas". So you can see the new dynamic array formulas as an [automated alternative](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4) for legacy CSE-Formulas with the addition to have a spill function amongst others.

---

***So to conclude:***

Your second formula could also be written:

```
=@SUMPRODUCT(--@IF(@ISNUMBER(N6:N9),N6:N9))
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work because only `SUMPRODUCT` natively cancels out the (unseen) logical operator, while `IF` only expects a scalar (single) value. So, unseen but effectively, your formula looks like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--@IF(@ISNUMBER(N6:N9),N6:N9))
```

However, pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will indeed rule out the logical operator and effectively make your formula look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--IF(ISNUMBER(N6:N9),N6:N9))
```

And thus being able to take arrays. Hopefully that clarified why you needed to press CSE with your second `IF` formula.

---

<sub>**Fun fact:**</sub>
 <sub>Next time, try to write `=@SUMPRODUCT(...` or `=@IF(...`. You'll notice that the formula is accepted but the logical operator disappears. A sign that this operator is used in the background =)</sub>

Comment: I also found the article about "implicit intersection" from your first link. The question could then be, if microsoft left that not disabling behavior on purpose or it was just forgotten. I will leave the question open for a bit, as i was expecting answers from you and Scott Craner. :)

Comment: @OverflowStacker, I tried to clarify it a bit more in my edit. The presence of implicit intersection is per design.