# Excel VBA - How to add dynamic array formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I am adding a formula to a worksheet via VBA which should be:

```
=UNIQUE(IF(TableA[ColumnA]=A1,TableA[ColumnB],""))
```

This utilises the new SPILL feature in Excel to give me a list of column B values where the related value in column A matches what is in cell A. I'm also applying the UNIQUE function to remove any multiple blank ("") results.

This works perfectly if I manually type the formula into Excel, however in using VBA to add the formula, Excel is adding @ symbols within the formula, and causing it to show #VALUE!.

The VBA line being used to add the formula is:

```
=Cells(x,y).Formula = "=UNIQUE(IF(TableA[ColumnA]=A1,TableA[ColumnB],""""))"
```

The resulting output in Excel is:

```
=@UNIQUE(IF(TableA[@[ColumnA]]=A1,TableA[ColumnB],""))
```

What is going on, and what have I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Good question, and I looked it up...

---

***<sub>In short:</sub>***

Use `=Cells(x,y).Formula2` instead of `=Cells(x,y).Formula`

---

***<sub>Explaination:</sub>***

The `@` that shows is called the implicit intersection operator. From MS docs:

> *Implicit intersection logic reduces many values to a single value. Excel did this to force a formula to return a single value, since a
>   cell could only contain a single value. If your formula was returning
>   a single value, then implicit intersection did nothing (even though it
>   was technically being done in the background).*

But why does it appear in your newer Excel O365? Well, `Range.Formula` uses IIE (implicit intersection) thus adding the `@` to basically undo your dynamic array functionality. [`UNIQUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) is a new dynamic array function. So, to write this out in code, you should use the [`Range.Formula2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2) property (or [`Range.Formula2R1C1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2r1c1) if you use `R1C1` notation). These properties use AE (array evaluation) and is now the default.

- [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2) is an informative doc from MS on the subject which explains the difference between `Formula` and `Formula2` in more detail.
- If you want to know more about the implicit intersection operator then have a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)
- I answered another question earlier on that involved implicit intersection with an example on how that actually works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58536210/9758194) if one finds it interesting.

Comment: What If I use formulalocal (for german) and there is not formulalocal2 in vba?