# When I use ActiveCell.value="my_custom_function" it inserts a @

Tags: excel, vba

When I use ActiveCell.value="my_custom_function" it inserts a @ between equal sign and my custom function,

Example:

```
ActiveCell.value = "=D_CHANGE()"
```

It returns =@D_CHANGE() to my active cell.

How can I avoid this @?

I think it is a configuration issue but don't figure out what it is.

Comment: Does using `ActiveCell.Formula2 = "=D_CHANGE()"` do the trick? If so, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/9758194) is the (basic) explaination.

Comment: @JvdV: `ActiveCell.value = "=D_CHANGE()"` also puts the formula into the cell, at least when I tried. That was a little bit surprising.

Comment: @Santiago Casas Rey: Do you have a function named `D_CHANGE()` ? If yes, please post the code.

Comment: @Storax, yes it's basically a string getting transformed into an formula through Excel

Comment: Thanks to all, specyally to @JvdV.
That was the reason.
I tried with `ActiveCell.value = "=D_CHANGE()"` and it worked

Comment: @JvdV the linked question isn't the same but it helped to resolve my doubt.
Sorry but I don't see how I can upvoting your answer.

Comment: @SantiagoCasasRey, cool that you solved it nonetheless =)