# Override Excel's new automatic addition of "@" sign in formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-365

### [EDIT] Ok so the solution is to use Formula2 or Formula2R1C1 instead of Formula or FormulaR1C1; just follow the [link below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula) in the third comment to understand better.
I'll leave my question here because I've spent a long time searching on MS docs, StackOverflow and Google in general, but found nothing... really a tricky issue to solve when you don't know Microsoft's "Implicit Intersection" keyword, because "@" is not a very search-friendly character. Hopefully my question here will help people get to [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)'s clear answer.

This really is a messed up way to handle things, always patching up instead of using a clean theoretical basis, but just business as usual for MS.

---

Excel now adds "@" sign in formulas automatically, and this makes my VBA-generated formulas wrong.
How can I disable this?

For instance, when I reference a whole column with a test such as `A2 = C:C`, Excel normally checks for each row in column `C` whether `A2` is equal to the row's value. However, when Excel decides to add a @ sign such as `A2 = @C:C` then it only checks whether `A2 = C2` and my formula does not work anymore.

I read in some places that the @ sign replaces the `ThisRow` keyword for Structured tables, but this does not help me much in knowing how to override it.

The issue is that my formula is generated in VBA, and the @ sign isn't added until after the VBA code terminates... so I cannot use a `Replace(myFormula, "@", "")`. Even if I force the range's formula calculation in VBA and overwrite formula with its value, it does not work.

Any ideas?

One more reason to avoid Microsoft...ughhhhh...I wish I could have used GSheets for this tool.

Comment: Can you share the formula in discussion, as your VBA code create it?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's not possible to tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/9758194). Basically use `Formula2`