# VBA keeps adding a ghost @ in my formula. Once I manually delete it, the formula works properly. How do I prevent this?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code to input a formula into G4 and autofill to the last row of data in column G. When I run the sub, it adds an @ symbol into the formula that is not supposed to be there. If I manually delete the @, the formula works perfectly. How do I stop this from being added? Code is as follows:

```
Range("G4:G" & lr).Formula = "=INDEX('[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(F4, ""*"" & '[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411&""*""), 0))"
```

The intended formula is:

```
=INDEX('[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(F4, ""*"" & '[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411&""*""), 0))
```

The resultant formula from running the sub is:

```
=INDEX('[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411, MATCH(1, COUNTIF(F4, "*"&@'[Academic Codes List.xlsx]List'!$A$2:$A$411&"*"), 0))
```

The ghost @ symbol is next to the first ampersand.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Try: `.FormulaArray` instead of `.Formula`

Comment: or: `.Formula2`  Realize that `.Formula2` is for Office 365 only.  If this is being ported to other non office 365 use the option above.

Comment: .FormulaArray produced an error saying "you cant change part of an array"

.Formula2 worked like a charm. Thank you sir!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/9758194). I marked it as a duplicate if you don't mind.

Comment: If this will used in non office 365 versions.  then you will need to iterate the cells in column G and insert the formula using `.FormulaArray` one at a time.

Comment: JvdV, no problem, I searched with very similar terminology to the title you linked to, and it did not come up, so thank you for sending me there!