# range.formula = ... Excel inserts a "@" and breaks how I want the formula to act

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a vba action that results in a Spilling formula.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Formula = "=NUMBERVALUE(" & topStore.Worksheet.Name & "!" & topStore.Address & ":" & botStore.Address & ")"
```

As a string variable, the value is

```
=NUMBERVALUE(Shipping!$A$2:$A$3592)
```

But when it lands in B1 it always has a @ in it and it results in a #VALUE! error.

```
=NUMBERVALUE(@Shipping!$A$2:$A$3592)
```

Is there a setting that I can disable or something I can add to the command that would prevent the @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
.Formula
```

with:

```
.Formula2
```

Comment: I can't believe I spent over an hour trying to Google an answer and the solution is this simple. Thank you

Comment: @DanielPiechowski  I STILL don't know when `.Formula2` is required.  If you find any info, Please update your question.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/11683?