# How to avoid @ character in Excel VBA when pasting a formula to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, named-ranges

When I try to make equal a cell with a formula containing a named range `MyRange`, the result will contain an unnecessary `@` character.

VBA code that I try to apply:

```
Sub InsertFormula()

Range("D1") = "=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,MyRange))"

End Sub
```

The result in the `D1` cell will be `=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,@MyRange))` and the `@` character ruins all the formula that works fine by writing it by hand without the `@` in the cell.

How Could I avoid character `@` in my result? Can you somebody help me in this matter?

Comment: Side note: try to fully qualify your range references, e.g. via `Sheet1.Range("D1")  ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Range("D1") = "=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,MyRange))"
```

with:

```
Range("D1").Formula2 = "=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,MyRange))"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid insertion of the so called *implicit intersection operator* using `.Formula2`:

```
Range("D1").Formula2 = "=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,MyRange))"
```

**Related links**

- [MS support: Implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)
- [How to add dynamic array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula/61138478#61138478)

Comment: That's right! Nice link too =). Though I think it's justified to have marked it as a duplicate for now.

Comment: Agree with comment; btw nice link indeed.