# Apache POI @ in the formula

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, excel-formula, apache-poi

I want to used and formula in Excel and the formula go like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(I118&E118, $A$8:$A$111&$F$8:$F$111,$P$8:$P$111)

=XLOOKUP(Value1&Value2, Range1 & Range2, RangeWhereisTheResult)
```

I put this formula in neatbeans java like this:

```
cell.setCellFormula("XLOOKUP(I118&E118, $A$8:$A$111&$F$8:$F$111,$P$8:$P$111)");
```

buy what i get in the excel is this:

```
=@XLOOKUP(I118&E118,@ $A$8:$A$111&@$F$8:$F$111,$P$8:$P$111)
```

I want to know how to avoid those `@`;

Comment: This is because of the new dynamic array functions. I don't know how to deal with array-formulas properly in apache-poi but the phenomenon is known. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/9758194)

Comment: Thank you! I going to study about this phenomenon and see if I  can get a solution, thanks!