# VBA’s Replace() function adds @ character in front of INDIRECT() function nested inside IF() function, breaking the whole formula in complex cases

Tags: excel, vba, replace, excel-formula, character

Suppose that my Excel workbook contains three worksheets called `Object1`, `Object2` and `Calculations`.

- In worksheet `Object1`, cell `A1` is called `Object1_Beginning` and
  contains the value `250`.
- In worksheet `Object2`, cell `B1` is called `Object2_Beginning` and contains the value `750`.

In worksheet `Calculations`, cell `A1` contains a formula of the following form:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONCAT("'Object1'!", ADDRESS(ROW(Object1!Object1_Beginning), COLUMN(Object1_Beginning)))) < 500, 1, 0)
```

*(I do not know why Excel sometimes removes the `'` characters when writing the names inside the `=ROW()` and `=COLUMN()` functions but it works just fine. I also know that using both `=INDIRECT()` as well as `=CONCAT()` is not actually needed in this case but I have a more complex formula at work where it is required in a similar way as shown in this example.)*

Then, I decided to write a macro that could replace the string `Object1` in `'Calculations'!A1`’s formula with `Object2` so that the result should look like this:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONCAT("'Object2'!", ADDRESS(ROW(Object2!Object2_Beginning), COLUMN(Object2_Beginning)))) < 500, 1, 0)
```

The macro code used for this purpose is written as follows:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1").Formula = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1").Formula, "Object1", "Object2", , , vbTextCompare)
```

However, the result then looks like this:

```
=IF(@INDIRECT(CONCAT("'Object2'!", ADDRESS(ROW(Object2!Object2_Beginning), COLUMN(Object2_Beginning)))) < 500, 1, 0)
```

I cannot remove the additional `@` character before the `=INDIRECT()` function by using the `Replace()` function in VBA. In this simple case, the formula still works and can calculate the correct result. Under more complex circumstances, however, this is not the case. Only when I then manually remove all the `@` characters, the calculation of the modified formula works correctly.

What can I do? I suppose that it has something to do with the `=INDIRECT()` function being nested inside the `=IF()` function but I cannot figure out how do fix this issue.

Comment: An annoying problem indeed. Probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/9758194) in a way. Please try `.Formula2` instead.

Comment: This has worked perfectly! Thank you very much. I did not find this question and it also has not been suggested to me. My new macro code now looks like this: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1").Formula2 = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calculations").Range("A1").Formula2, "Object1", "Object2", , , vbTextCompare)`

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me sign this as a duplicate =)

Comment: Ok. Should I delete my question now or should I let it exist so that people may find the solution to this problem when they are specifically looking for “the `@` character problem”?

Comment: Definately let it exist. It appears to be hard to find "@" in search queries but any lead can help =)