# How to prevent Excel/XlsxWriter randomly adding @ character in my formulas

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

**Context**

I use [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter) to write some data into an xlsx file from a [python](/questions/tagged/python) code.
I need to fill a cell with a formula that calculates the average of a specific column (that contains time values).

**Problem Description**

I noticed that when I try to open my document with Excel, it automatically adds an '@' symbol right before my range which makes my formula calculation fail...
If I manually remove this extra '@', the formula works perfectly as expected.

It is really annoying to have to manually fix my formula like that since I have a lot of similar average calculations that are broken because of this.
I read that it is Excel that adds it so it seems to be no way to prevent this undesired behaviour programmatically from my python code with the xlsxwriter API.

**Question**

Does someone know if there is a way to prevent Excel to perform any modification of my formulas ?

**What I have tried so far**

I already tried to [*"protect"*](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#protect) all of my sheets (make them read-only) but it seems to apply only for the user, not for Excel...

---

**Example**

Here is an example of my issue (to make it more understandable that this load of plain text).

From my python code, if I write the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(B2:B8))
```

After opening the document, Excel automatically changes the formula as:

```
=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(@B2:B8))
```

Which make the result of the calculation become:

> `#VALUE!`

If I undo what Excel does by manually restoring my formula (manually edit the cell and remove the '@'), I get the desired calculated average value as I expected it to be.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula).

Comment: @BigBen Yes I already have found that kind of answers but it's in VBA.

Comment: @Fareanor `@` is the implicit intersection operator.  BigBen's point was that the solution to your problem is to write to `.Formula2` rather than `.Formula`.  If xlswriter doesn't (yet) support that, it a failing of xlswriter, not Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if Excel inserts a `@` in a formula written by XlsxWriter it means that formula is an array formula and should have been written with `worksheet.write_array_formula()` (although there are some caveats, see below).

So with a variant of your example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_array_formula('A1', '=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(B1:B6))')

worksheet.write_column('B1', ['2:30'] * 6)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

However, recent versions of Excel have introduced dynamic formulas and dynamic arrays. I think what you are seeing here is the [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us). <s>I am currently working on support for dynamic formulas and arrays in XlsxWriter but it is still under investigation</s>.

**Update**

As of release 1.4.1, May 2021, XlsxWriter supports [dynamic arrays](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dynamic-array-support) so the above example could be changed to use `write_dynamic_array_formula()` like this:

```py
worksheet.write_dynamic_array_formula('A1', '=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(B1:B6))')
```

Which would give the following output in Excel 365 (note that it no longer has `@` or the array formula braces `{}`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. [`write_array_formula()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_array_formula) doesn't accept a single cell (`A1` in your example) but a range (the input parameters). It's strange that your example works (it doesn't for me). Maybe it's because I use the row-column version. Anyway, I tried to add the brackets `{}` around my formula as you also suggested and it seems to work !