# FILTER function using Excel VBA only generating one line of data instead of a list. Why is "@" (This Row) symbol being added? How can I prevent this?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula

I'll save you a long-winded explanation and keep this short and sweet. Basically I want to use VBA to create a list, which is a list made up of common values between two other lists (zip codes). Essentially I want to do an `INNER JOIN` for those folks familiar with SQL. I can do it easily by typing in the formula in the first cell directly, using `=FILTER(list1,COUNTIF(list2,list1))` to accomplish this join: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(inputs!R8C7:R3610C7,COUNTIF(CleanVGRevenue!R9C2:R1027C2,inputs!R8C7:R3610C7)))` and this method automatically fills out the entire joined list/table to the proper size, which is what I want. Great. So I went to put this into VBA, because I want an automated solution, replacing the hard coded values with variables that adjust to the number of zips in each list (n & nVGR):

```
Sub JoinCommon()
    Dim sInput: Set sInput = Workbooks("VGadjustment.xlsm").Sheets("inputs")
    Dim n: Let n = sInput.Cells(5, 8).Value
    Dim cVGR: Set cVGR = Workbooks("VGadjustment.xlsm").Sheets("CleanVGRevenue")
    Dim nVGR: Let nVGR = cVGR.Cells(1, 3).Value
    cVGR.Cells(9, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=UNIQUE(FILTER(inputs!R8C7:R" & n + 7 & "C7,COUNTIF(CleanVGRevenue!R9C2:R" & nVGR + 8 & "C2,inputs!R8C7:R" & n + 7 & "C7)))"
End Sub
```

This almost works, however when the macro runs, the formula being entered to the cell is actually replaced with `=@UNIQUE(FILTER(inputs!R8C7:R3610C7,COUNTIF(CleanVGRevenue!R9C2:R1027C2,inputs!R8C7:R3610C7)))` Note the **@** symbol. Since excel puts this in, it only returns the first line and does not fill down automatically like I want. I get what the symbol does, but I don't want it there. How do I stop excel from putting it in automatically when using VBA? *Why* is put in automatically?

Thank you all for any help. It's greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/av5nV.jpg) is an image of what I have currently, and here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV98y.jpg) is an image of what I want to have happen. I would imbed the pics if I could but I guess I need 10 reputation to be able to post images.

Comment: In order to avoid `@`, try using `Formula2` instead of `Formula`.

Comment: Or in this case, `.Formula2R1C1`.

Comment: Awesome thank you all, .Formula2R1C1 worked perfectly. Also thank you to whoever sent this link, where the question is also answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula