# When i write a formula in excel using xlwings it makes a @

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I'm trying to find all the UNIQUE numbers of a column, but when i use the Excel function UNIQUE Excel makes a @ infront. I use xlwings, and have used (if, sum, average) function without any problems.

`sheet.range('X1').value = ['=UNIQUE(A:A,FALSE,FALSE)']`

Then excel writes it as: `=@UNIQUE(A:A;FALSE;FALSE)`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/9758194) answer is related and will explain why it's happening. However, I would not know the correct syntax for xlwings to add array functionality. I can't imagine `.Value` does any good though.