# Excel VBA - Insert Formula Incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I'm trying dynamically to get some data from closed workbooks so I couldn't use Indirect or Index formula to do. So, I developed a code that insert the formula every time I create a worksheet. The code works fine apart from the issue explain below, so I haven't included the whole code, but just the bit I'm struggling.

I'm trying to insert the following formula into to a range like so:

```
Sub Create_WS_from_Overview()
Dim txt1 As String, txt2 As String, txt3 As String
Dim formtxt As String

txt1 = "=TRANSPOSE(FILTER("
txt2 = "'C://path/[Part_of_Workbook_Name_"
txt3 = ".xlsx]WorksheetName'!$C$3:$W$3"
      
formtxt = txt1 & txt2 & ActiveSheet.Name & txt3 & ", " & txt2 & ActiveSheet.Name & txt3 & "<>0))"
        
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Formula = formtxt
End Sub
```

The code works fine but it's inserting `@` in the formula so it doesn't give the range I want.

Do you have any ideas why it does that and how to fix it? (If I manually remove it the `@` works fine)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I actually used `.Formula2` and it worked. Not sure why. Any explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula