# Created Custom Formula is showing @ why?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7, vba6

[image]

Formula is showing @ symbol. why it is showing. and how can i solve it.

Comment: Use `Formula2`; see [How to add dynamic array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula/61138478#61138478) ?

Answer (score 0):

i got resolved by using ActiveCell.Formula2