# Get the position of smallest Offset value from a Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list with prices with MoQ (minimum order quantity) next to them. Some suppliers however like to make it extra complicated by having an additional price-list with possible cheaper prices for a same MoQ.

To get the right result, I need the smallest price but since we have different prices with different MoQ's already in the database, I need to link them correctly. So if one reference with MoQ 2 has new prices, I need to check for the lowest price with said MoQ.

Here's a test table:

| MoQ Reference | Which price? | Price1 | MoQ1 | Price2 | MoQ2 | ExtraPrice1 | ExtraMoQ1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 |  | 189 | 1 | 182 | 2 | 176.89 | 1 |
| 1 |  | .75 | 5 |  |  | 1 | 1 |

The preferred outcome would be the name (for clarity to my supervisor to see which price was chosen) aka "ExtraPrice1" for B2 but I'm ok with just the price (176.89), I can work from there.
As for B3, it should also be "ExtraPrice1" since ExtraMoQ1 is the only corresponding MoQ for A3.

I tried the following in B2:

> =INDEX(C$1:H$1, MATCH(1,INDEX(C2:H2=A2)*(MOD(COLUMN(C2:H2),2)=1),0)-1)))

Gotten result: `Price 1`
The reason for the MOD() is because I don't want to accidentally match with a price instead of an MoQ (see row 3).
I tried it with MIN(C2:H2) in there as well but got an error #NA iirc. The index gives an array of 0's and 1's so I don't know how to get the lowest price which is to the left of said 1's in the array.

Also tried a different formula I found but it got the same result (the first found match)

> =INDEX(C$1:H$1, SMALL(IF((C2:H2=A2),ROW(1:1)),1))

Don't fully understand this one with ROW(1:1) there but thought I'd give it a try regardless.

Then I tried using something I didn't find online but thought could work

> =INDEX(C$1:H$1,MIN(OFFSET(FILTER(C2:H2,C2:H2=A2),,-1)))

but alas, I get an error; probably since Filter just returns the MoQ's found equal to A2 instead of the locations..

If I understood the functions better, I could figure out to get the position of the lowest value next to the found positions from the inner `INDEX` of the first formula but clearly I'm not there yet. There's always VBA I could fall back to but didn't think I'd learn the functions if I didn't bother with them once in a while.

Comment: You've said "see row 3" but there are only 2 rows in your example table

Comment: Row 1 = header, row 3 is the last row in the table @CHill60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=BYROW(2:3,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,WRAPROWS(TOROW(DROP(x,,2),3),2),MIN(FILTER(TAKE(y,,1),DROP(y,,1)<=@+x)))))
```

The idea here is that we can loop complete rows, therefor account for whatever amount of columns lay ahead as long as Price/MoQ is written in pairs. So:

- Loop each row, using variable 'x'. Note, here 'x' is still a *range* object which is important in the next few steps;
- Create a nested variable 'y' which is a wrapped array of two columns after we remove the 1st two cells and used `TOROW()` to remove empty *cells* from our *range*  object 'x';
- Now we can `FILTER()` the 1st column of our wrapped variable 'y' based on the 2nd column where the values of this 2nd column are '<=' to **@+x**. Using implicit intersection to return the 1st value in an array, hence the use of '+x' to turn the *range* object into an array first.

Comment: I can follow/visualize everything in my head until the `<=@+x`, explicitly the @ I'm not familiar with. Does it not look at the MoQ in A-column? My actual data starts further in the sheet, i.e. AM2:BJ2 for the range with prices/MoQ so I suppose I should qualify that as the range object but my MoQ to compare with would be F2 so I wouldn't be able to use @+x? I also just noticed that I'm an idiot in my explanation; if I wanted the MoQ's to be the same, it should be Price2 for B2 but you understood what I meant, luckily =)

Comment: Well you can still use the same principle provided that you don't have any values in columns after BJ. So: `=BYROW(2:3,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,WRAPROWS(TOROW(DROP(x,,38),3),2),MIN(FILTER(TAKE(y,,1),DROP(y,,1)<=INDEX(x,6))))))`. Note that we can't use implicit intersection operator ('@') here nomore. If you are unfamiliar with implicit intersection, maybe visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula/61138478#61138478) post and at the bottum there are some helpfull links for you to follow up on.

Comment: Alright, that was an interesting read, I'll check if I can make it work (since I do have values after BJ but those could technically all be ignored) after lunch.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, that would be a matter of one more nested `TAKE()` to make sure you only use `AM2:BJ2` here: `=BYROW(2:3,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,WRAPROWS(TOROW(TAKE(DROP(x,,38),,24),3),2),MIN(FILTER(TAKE(y,,1),DROP(y,,1)<=INDEX(x,6))))))`

Comment: It was my fault for asking a poorly worded/too simplified question to my actual situation, sorry for the needed edits ^^ With the `<=INDEX(x,6)` part I feared it'd take a smaller MoQ even if the desired MoQ was higher (i.e. Desired MoQ being 2, possible ones being 5,2 and 1) but your formula still works even in those situations since I still want the cheapest value even if the MoQ is lower but not if it's higher. Thanks for the help and explanation!

Comment: The only edit I needed to add was `DROP(x,,COL(AL$1)` to make it a bit more flexible to add columns in between F2 and the price-range afterwards =)

Comment: creative; I like the touch of `@+x`

Answer (score 2):

Edit based on updated question:

Use the following formula:
`=@LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOROW(VSTACK(C$1:H$1,C2:H2),,1),4),SORT(FILTER(w,TAKE(w,,-1)=A2),2))`

[image]

Or for the values only:
`=@LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOROW(C2:H2,,1),2),SORT(FILTER(w,TAKE(w,,-1)=A2),2))`

---

*previous answer based on original question*

If I understood correctly, this  returns the name of the cheapest value name for listed ExtraPrice:

`=XLOOKUP(H2,DROP(WRAPCOLS(C2:F2,2),1),IFNA(IFS(TAKE(WRAPCOLS(C2:F2,2)<=G2,1),TAKE(WRAPCOLS(C$1:F$1,2),1)),G$1))`

[image]

Comment: The more time goes by, the more I feel I wrongly explained things/simplified the situation.. The A-column is what to compare to for MoQ, sometimes there's the same MoQ, i.e. MoQ1 = ExtraMoQ1, to which I need to get the cheapest price. My actual range of prices/MoQ's is 24 columns long.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Please check updated answer. Let me know if that works if you update it to your ranges. PS note the `$` in the header row `C$1:F$1`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this will help me correct the inconsistencies I have between existing MoQ's and the new ones quite easily! I had no doubt both you and Jvdv would manage my issue and I'll try to learn from both as well :)

Comment: When I edited your code to `SORT(FILTER(w,TAKE(w,,-1)<=A2),2)` (to account for when the MoQ is lower but also the price is lower (easier to order for us) but I figured the sort with default ascending sorting would take care of the rest but it took the highest MoQ (but equally lowest value), i.e. there was a `Price 29.1 with MoQ 5` | `Price 27 with MoQ 10` | `Price 27 with MoQ 1`  and it took the MoQ 10 because the MoQ reference was also 10 (A2 in your formula). Wasn't my understanding/edit of your formula correct? Sorry for troubling you again.

Comment: Yes, It filters out any header price names/ price values where the (Extra)MoQ# equals the MoQ Reference. The filtered array is sorted by the price values ascending and the first name or value of the sorted array (depending on which formula you use) is returned, so this  always equals the smallest value or it's header name.

Comment: Aha, so an inner sort worked to fix my issue :) `SORT(SORT(FILTER(w,TAKE(w,,-1)<=A2),1),2)`

Comment: Not sure what the issue was. But wouldn't this be the same?: `SORT(FILTER(w,TAKE(w,,-1)<=A2),{1,2})`

Comment: Since the price with MoQ 10 came first in the array, when sorting it stayed on top hence the need for an additional sort. Didn't know that {1,2} was a possibility, the gift of learning keeps on coming! :D Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

With older versions of Excel e.g. 2013 you can apply this formula alternatively. Enter the formula as an arrayformula with CSE if you don't have Office 365 or Excel for the web or a recent Excel version.

=SMALL(IF((D2:H2<=A2)*NOT(ISBLANK(D2:H2)),IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2:G2)),C2:G2)),1)
[image: Get the position of smallest Offset value from a Index Match]