# Excel adds "@" to SWITCH and creates #NAME error, when first opened. Why?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, export-to-excel, excel-web-addins

I have a google doc spreadsheet, where I calculate name of the weekday based on date. I do it with formula:

```
=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(B3),1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")
```

So the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

I would like to export it into Excel and then send it via outlook and possibly open in WEB Excel app. After Exporting and opening in a WEB Excel, I see that the formula is prepended with a extra `@`:

```
=@SWITCH(WEEKDAY(B3),1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")
```

Which I thought was the cause of `#NAME?` error, which is shown in web based outlook and web based excel:

[image]

I would like open file in a based WEB Excel app.

**UPDATE**
Following advice from the comments I have unzipped the file and checked the worksheets/sheet.xml. The xml contains the rule without the "@":

```
<f t="shared" ref="A3:A31" si="1">SWITCH(WEEKDAY(B3),1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")</f>
```

So, `@` may not be the reason for `#NAME?` error. How to fix this `#NAME?` error with  this formula, if it is not created by `@`?

Comment: I tested with an *arrayformula* (https://i.imgur.com/SLuCKkC.png); weirdly the output data remained intact but the formula totally vanished in excel web!

Comment: Are you sure it's added by Google sheets? Maybe excel added it on it's own, when the file is opened.

Comment: @TheMaster how to check who added it?

Comment: Only way to know for sure is to examine the xml file(Excel file is a zip file, which when opened contains xml, which can be manually inspected). But excel is known to add these, when old excel is opened in new excel programs. See https://superuser.com/questions/1525270/ and https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-functions-that-return-ranges-or-arrays-7d1970e2-cbaa-4279-b59c-b9dd3900fc69

Comment: Regardless, your issue seems to be `#NAME?` error. Correct?  I'm not sure whether that's related to `@` at all. AFAIK, `@` doesn't seem to be the reason for the error. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286

Comment: @TheMaster I have followed your advice and you were right. The xml file does not contain the "@" :           <f t="shared" ref="A3:A31" si="1">SWITCH(WEEKDAY(B3),1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5, "Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")</f>

Comment: @TheMaster after I remove the "@" then the formula works just fine in web based Excel

Comment: @fascy Ok. If you add `@` back, does it cause the same `#NAME?` error?

Comment: @TheMaster After I added it again it still works, no #NAME issue just "Thursday" as expected.. So now I am confused

Comment: Not an excel expert. Maybe their experts can answer. One of their experts asked what excel you were using - excel for web or desktop. You might wanna add that info to your question, as well as rephrase the question to focus more on the `#NAME` error rather than the `@`

Comment: @TheMaster I have updated the post and added info: I would like open file in a based WEB Excel app.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I am sorry but I do not know what is arrayformula  and I do not know how to use your example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257021/discussion-between-fascynacja-and-themaster).

Comment: Ohh its just some insight, not some working method or so. Again not an expert with excel but the below suggested answer would work with excel web. It has the **Find and replace (all)** option. Replace *=@* with *=* & formulas are working normal.  Until someone has a solution I'd say this can be the workaround...

Comment: @rockinfreahshow I need to send an excel which will be opened by someone in view only mode in outlook. So no changes can be applied at this step.

Comment: Fix the excel file in excel web(using *find & replace*) then download it as *xlsx* file & send this new file to the person. Just tested and it works this way (no more *@* appended to the formula)

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I would like to have more automated process. If I have to 1) send it first to myself, 2) open in excel web 3)edit and then send to the person I prefere to copy the values from the columns and put them fixed: "Thursday", "Friday" etc.  I need to send it many times like that  and I would like to optimize the process.

Comment: If you only need the data to be visible as intended to the end person, doesnt my first comment (with screenshot) work. I mean I know you said you dont know much about google sheet arrayformulas but maybe you could look into it...

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I will give it a try. thats a good advice. Also if you would like to post your formulas as working answer I will be glad to accept if it works:)

Comment: The `@` [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/11683) the source of the error. Like you [have discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78079628/excel-adds-to-switch-and-creates-name-error-when-first-opened-why#comment137651724_78079628), the source of the error is that Excel needs to re-evaluate the cell for whatever reason, which happens when you re-enter the formula, with or without the `@`. Maybe the google-generated file is not exactly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *this is just a workaround to OPs situation & not an intended solution that solves the `@` character that gets prepended to `switch()` when uploaded to excel-web*

*An alternative formula (`to OPs switch()`) which somehow retains **ONLY** the data (formula vanishes) when downloaded as .xlsx file and uploaded to `excel-web`*

```js
={"header";
 index(if(len(B3:B),xlookup(weekday(B3:B),sequence(7),text(sequence(7),"dddd"),),))}
```

[image]

Comment: If I may ask how to stop this formula to process rows after lets say row number 13 ? The formula works as expected, and also after exporting to excel and sending it via outlook it looks like expected. Only I have some other data in lets say B14, B15 which is not a date and I dont want to process it.

Comment: restrict the range as such: use `B3:B13` instead of `B3:B` within the formula

Answer (score 0):

Conversions from Google Sheets loose formulas functionality, I guess the faster way would be directly using CTRL+H in the Excel file and replace “@“ with “”.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).