# Excel VBA - My VBA code to input formulas into specific cells gives me "=@IF( ......)" instead of "=IF(....)"

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

My VBA code is supposed to build a pre-filled table with formulas based on the column position as well as data validation to integrate a list. The list is working fine, but for the formulas, I'll let you see in the image what I'm getting, and I'll also share my code afterward:

```vb
Sub CreerTableau()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nombrePhases As Integer
    Dim derniereligne As Long
    Dim plage As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Demander à l'utilisateur de saisir le nombre de phases
    nombrePhases = InputBox("Veuillez saisir le nombre de phases :")
    
    ' Vérifier si l'utilisateur a saisi un nombre valide
    If Not IsNumeric(nombrePhases) Or nombrePhases <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Veuillez saisir un nombre valide de phases.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Définition de la feuille de calcul
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test Essai")
    
    ' Trouver la dernière ligne du tableau
    derniereligne = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Définir la plage pour le nouveau tableau
    Set plage = ws.Range("B9:I" & derniereligne + nombrePhases)
    
    ' Mettre en place la validation de données dans la colonne D
    With ws.Range("D9:D" & derniereligne + nombrePhases).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=MP"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    ' Remplir les formules pour les colonnes C, E, G, H et I
    For i = 9 To derniereligne + nombrePhases
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=SI($D" & i & "="""","""",RECHERCHEV($D" & i & ",DECALER(BDD!$A$4:$Z$4,0,0,NBVAL(BDD!$A:$Z)-1),2,FAUX))"
        ws.Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=SIERREUR(SI($D" & i & "="""","""",RECHERCHEV($D" & i & ",DECALER(BDD!$A$4:$Z$4,0,0,NBVAL(BDD!$A:$Z)-1),9,FAUX)),""Données manquantes"")"
        ws.Cells(i, 7).Formula = "=SI(F" & i & "<>"""",(F" & i & "/100)*$F$4,""Saisir %Matière"")"
        ws.Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=SI(D" & i & "<>"""","" g"","""")"
        ws.Cells(i, 9).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00" ' Format monétaire euro
        ws.Cells(i, 9).Formula = "=SIERREUR(SI($D" & i & "="""","""",RECHERCHEV($D" & i & ",DECALER(BDD!$A$4:$Z$4,0,0,NBVAL(BDD!$A:$Z)-1),4,FAUX))*F" & i & "/100,"""")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

In each of the formulas, as you can see in the screenshot, the `=` sign is always preceded by the `@` sign, which renders all the formulas non-functional so need help about this if it's possible.

[image: VBA results in the worksheet]

I tried adding this line of code before the last `End Sub` to fix the issue, but without success:

```vb
' Supprimer les "@" après les signes "=" dans les formules
plage.Replace What:="=@", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: Look at this: **[Why does excel put @ in formula from VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/8162520)**

Comment: While the `@` sign may or may not be changing the behaviour of your formulas, it is not the reason you are getting the `#NAME!` errors. The reason is that you are not using the English function names in your code.

Comment: If you want to use the local function names you can use `Formula2Local` (also takes care of the `@` issue)   If you need your worksheet to work across multiple locales though it's best to use the English/US function names in VBA.