# What's the difference between @INDEX (with at sign) and INDEX?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I bumped into the following formula in Excel `=@INDEX(B100:B110, C100)` and was wondering what's the difference with `=INDEX(B100:B110, C100)` as they both appear to do the same thing. The use-case is to lookup the value of a ComboBox and place it in the cell with such formula.

Comment: [Implicit intersection operator: @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)

Comment: In brief `@` operator return only first value from array output instead of many values.

Comment: Not sure if we can call these duplicates, but related for more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534445/how-to-distinguish-if-sumproduct-needs-to-be-inserted-with-cse-or-not/58536210#58536210). It will explain the `@`.

Comment: About the 2nd part of the question: As is, your formula is not going to lookup anything. Do you rather want to use `VLOOKUP()` or combine `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`? Even `FILTER()` or `XLOOKUP()` maybe?

Comment: @JvdV can you please provide a proper answer with example / use case? that would be much more useful for a lot of people and me :) rather than inconclusive comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments;

---

**Theory:**

The `@` is called the Implicit Intersection Operator. See an extensive explaination in the official [MS-documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34). Which states:

> *"Implicit intersection logic reduces many values to a single value. Excel did this to force a formula to return a single value, since a cell could only contain a single value. If your formula was returning a single value, then implicit intersection did nothing (even though it was technically being done in the background)..."*

Also:

> *"Generally speaking, functions that (**CAN**!!) return multi-cell ranges or arrays will be prefixed with @ if they were authored in an older version of Excel."*

As you stated, you encountered this operator in the formula `=@INDEX(B100:B110, C100)`. In fact, this is a textbook example as quite literally an example given at the previous linked documentation.

Note how I added the word "**CAN**" in the quote above. Formulae that can't return array will not be preceded by an `@`. In your case the author of the formula meant to return a single value (I pressume). However, Excel does not know this (or rather does not bother analyse this) and adds the `@` when you open the workbook in a newer ms365 environment to *make sure there is no difference in how the formula will work*.

---

**Sample:**

Imagine the following sample data:

| A |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |

If an author in an excel version prior to 365 would write `=INDEX(A1:A3,0)` this would automatically be (though in the background) processed as `=@INDEX(A1:A3,0)`; thus using implicit intersection, and return `B` as a result.

Opening this workbook in 365 will automatically recognize this formula and the use of implicit intersection and show `=@INDEX(A1:A3,0)`. Would you remove the implicit intersection operator, ms365 will revert to it's standard: dynamic arrays, and thus will spill down the entire array referenced in the 1st parameter:

[image]

---

**Related:**

For additional information about practical encounters of the implicit intersection operator:

- [Excel VBA - How to add dynamic array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138029/excel-vba-how-to-add-dynamic-array-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to distinguish if sumproduct needs to be inserted with CSE or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534445/how-to-distinguish-if-sumproduct-needs-to-be-inserted-with-cse-or-not)